# Split $\{1,2,...,3n\}$ into triples with $x+y=4z$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, combinatorial-designs

A similar question  appeared last week.

[For which $n\in\Bbb N$ can we divide $\{1,2,3,...,3n\}$ into $n$ subsets each with $3$ elements such that in each subset $\{x,y,z\}$ we have $x+y=3z$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4179825/for-which-n-in-bbb-n-can-we-divide-1-2-3-3n-into-n-subsets-each-wi/4186633?noredirect=1#comment8689058_4186633)

> In this problem, I want to split the integers from $1$ to $3n$ into triples $\{x,y,z\}$ with $x+y=4z$ instead of $3z$.

I have a set of solutions, but am looking  for more ideas.

$\sum(x+y+z)=\sum5z$ so $n=5k$ or $5k+3$.  There are already hundreds of solutions for $n=13$, and I imagine that number will only increase with $n$, but the trick is to find one for any particular $n$.

Any solution for $n=N$ can be extended to one for each of $n=19N-7,19N+8,19N+13$.  That gives solutions for $3^m$ different $n$ below $Z=19^m$, which is more than $\sqrt[3]Z$ different $n$ below $Z$.  But most solutions do not contain a smaller one within them.

To split the numbers from $3N+1$ to $57N-21$ into triples
$$(3N+1+k,33N-9+3k,9N-2+k)$$ for $k =0..6N-4$ and
$$(51N-18+k,33N-10+3k,21N-7+k)\\
(27N-9+k,33N-11+3k,15N-5+k)$$ for $k =0..6N-3$.

A way to split $\{3N+1,...,3(19N+8)\}$ into triples is $$(3N+1+k,33N+15+3k,9N+4+k)\\ (51N+22+k,33N+14+3k,21N+9+k)$$ for $k=0..6N+2$, and $$(27N+12+k,33N+16+3k,15N+7+k)$$ for $k=0..6N+1$

To split $\{3N+1 ...,3(19N+13)\}$ into triples
$$(3N+1+k,33N+23+3k,9N+6+k)$$ for $k=0..6N+4$ and $$(27N+19+k,33N+25+3k,15N+11+k)\\
(51N+36+k,33N+24+3k,21N+15+k)$$ for $k=0..6N+3$.

At [Split $\{1,...,3n\}$ into triples with $x+y=5z$ - no solutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195206/split-1-3n-into-triples-with-xy-5z-no-solutions), Thomas Andrews has shown there are no solutions for $x+y=5z$.

Comment: @Aqua a difference between that question and our questions is that the odd-one-out is the average of the others, so the basic solution can be copied and shifted without affecting that.  In our cases it is more difficult to build one solution using a smaller solution.

Comment: Why not in $\{1,2,\ldots, 4n \}$ instead? Just curious

Comment: $x,y,z$ is three numbers per equation.  You could do $(w,x,y,z)$ with $w+x+y=4z$