# Given numbers $1$ to $3n$, construct $n$ equations of the form $a + b = c$ or $a \times b = c$ such that each number is used exactly once.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, arithmetic

> Given numbers $1$ to $3n$, construct $n$ equations of the form $a + b = c$ or $a \times b = c$ such that each number is used exactly once.

For example:

```
n=1 => 1+2=3
n=2 => 1+4=5, 2x3=6
n=3 => 4+5=9, 1+7=8, 2x3=6
```

The question is, does a solution exist for every n?

I tried writing a basic program and it becomes too slow after n = 14. Here are the solutions I have so far:

```
1 ['1+2=3']
2 ['2*3=6', '1+4=5']
3 ['4+5=9', '1+7=8', '2*3=6']
4 ['3+6=9', '1+10=11', '4+8=12', '2+5=7']
5 ['2+8=10', '3+6=9', '1+13=14', '5+7=12', '11+4=15']
6 ['3*5=15', '2+8=10', '4+14=18', '6+11=17', '7+9=16', '1+12=13']
7 ['6+12=18', '3*5=15', '7+10=17', '1+20=21', '4+9=13', '2+14=16', '8+11=19']
8 ['8+14=22', '6+12=18', '7+10=17', '2+19=21', '1+15=16', '11+13=24', '4+5=9', '3+20=23']
9 ['6+19=25', '8+14=22', '4+13=17', '2+18=20', '1+26=27', '3+7=10', '9+15=24', '5+16=21', '11+12=23']
10 ['6+19=25', '14+15=29', '11+17=28', '4+26=30', '2+18=20', '1+21=22', '3*9=27', '8+16=24', '5+7=12', '10+13=23']
11 ['10+23=33', '6+19=25', '14+15=29', '11+17=28', '4+26=30', '2+18=20', '5+27=32', '1+12=13', '9+22=31', '3*7=21', '16+8=24']
12 ['10+23=33', '3+29=32', '6+19=25', '15+21=36', '11+17=28', '8+14=22', '4+16=20', '7+27=34', '2*12=24', '1+30=31', '5+13=18', '9+26=35']
13 ['10+23=33', '3+29=32', '7+30=37', '6+19=25', '5+34=39', '15+21=36', '11+17=28', '18+20=38', '4+31=35', '1+26=27', '9+13=22', '8+16=24', '2+12=14']
14 ['10+23=33', '4+37=41', '3+29=32', '9+25=34', '15+21=36', '11+17=28', '8+14=22', '6+24=30', '13+27=40', '5*7=35', '2+18=20', '1+38=39', '12+19=31', '16+26=42']
```

Here's the code for the program:

````
def main(n):
    r = set(range(1, n*3+1))
    print(n, solve(n, r, []))

def solve(n, lst, solution):
    if not lst:
        if len(solution) != n:
            return False
        return solution
    cs = set(combinations(lst, 3))
    for c in cs:
        valid_solution = valid(c)
        if valid_solution:
            new_solution = solution + [valid_solution]
            result = solve(n, set(lst) - set(c), new_solution)
            if result:
                return result
    return False

def valid(lst):
    a = lst[0]
    b = lst[1]
    c = lst[2]
    if a + b == c:
        return "%s+%s=%s" % (a, b, c)
    if a * b == c:
        return "%s*%s=%s" % (a, b, c)
    return False
```
````

Comment: If you have a solution for $n$ using only addition, you can get a solution for $4n$ using only addition.  

> 1. Double all the numbers from the solutionvto $n$.  That uses all the even numbers up to $6n$.  
> 2. $(2k-1)+(9n+1-k)=(9n+k),k=1..3n$

Comment: o that's cool! how did you come up with that?

Comment: There was a similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4179825/for-which-n-in-bbb-n-can-we-divide-1-2-3-3n-into-n-subsets-each-wi/4186633?noredirect=1#comment8689058_4186633

Comment: This is a special case of the problem known as “[exact cover by 3-sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover)”.  The "3-sets" here are the triples $\{ a, b, c\}$ where $a+b=c$ or $a×b=c$.  Although no good methods are known to solve the exact cover problem in general, algorithms to solve it often run quickly in practice and would work for your special case.

Comment: http://plover.com/~mjd/misc/x3c.txt contains a Python program that generates one or more solutions, and is fast enough to use for at least $n$ up to 60.  For example, here's a solution for $n=39$, which took 6 seconds on my laptop: `[(10, 23, 33), (2, 18, 20), (1, 12, 13), (3, 22, 25), (11, 16, 27), (6, 32, 38), (5, 24, 29), (15, 21, 36), (7, 30, 37), (8, 26, 34), (4, 35, 39), (14, 17, 31), (9, 19, 28)]`.  The `(10, 23, 33)` means $10+23+33$ and similarly the others.  I hope you find it instructive.

Comment: Tweak my earlier method to get a solution for $4n+1$.  Then you can recurse to get a solution whenever $n$ in base 4 contains only 0s and 1s.  For example 1,4,5,16,17,20,21.  That gives $2^k$ solutions for $n\lt4^k$

Comment: @MJD oh interesting! Didn't know this fit into a bigger kind of problem. I came up with it based on a dream I had :P Your approach of generating all the solutions is helpful, I'll play around with it and see if there are any other patterns.

Comment: Let the $a$ be the numbers from $1$ to $n$, then the $b$ and $c$ form a Skolem set.  Thorall Skolem showed in 1957 there is a suitable set of $b$ and $c$ whenever $n$ is a multiple of $4$, or one more than a multiple of $4$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langford_pairing

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A014552 A Langford pairing for $n-1$ gives a Skolem set for $n$ by putting $b_1$ and $c_1=b_1+1$ at either end of the interval.

Comment: Oh nice! Based on this @ricky-tensor looks like addition-only solution always exist for n=0, 1 mod 4

Answer (score 3):

Thinking about multiplication sounds hard, so I'll try with just addition.

In the equation $a+b=c$ we'll say that $a,b$ are "left numbers" and $c$ is a "right number". Let $L$ be the set of left numbers and $R$ be the set of right numbers. Then $|L|=2n$ and $|R|=n$.

By adding all the equations together, we have:

$$
\sum_{l\in L} l= \sum_{r\in R}r
$$

The sum of all the numbers is:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{3n}k = \frac{3n(3n+1)}{2} = \frac{9}{2}n^2+\frac{3}{2}n
$$

This is just the sum of left and right numbers, so:

$$
\frac{3n(3n+1)}{2} = \sum_{l\in L} l + \sum_{r\in R}r = 2\sum_{l\in L}l = 2\sum_{r\in R}r
$$

So:

$$
\sum_{r\in R}r = \frac{3n(3n+1)}{4}
$$

For $n=0,1\mod 4$ this formula results in an integer, but for $n=2,3\mod 4$, it results in a non-integer. So the task is impossible to do using only addition for $n=2,3\mod 4$.

Are the remaining cases possible? I haven't been able to prove that there's always a solution for $n=0,1\mod 4$, though it seems like there is. This C code can quickly find solutions using only addition for $n$ up to about 60.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 60

char used[N+1];

// return 0 if impossible to solve, 1 otherwise
// m is the maximum unused number, all other state is saved in "used"
int solve(int m) {
    while (used[m]) {
        m--;
        if (m == 0) return 1; // all numbers used, solving successful
    }
    for (int k = (m-1)/2; k >= 1; k--) { // counting down is much faster than couting up! (a solution that splits m nearly evenly is more likely to be correct)
        if ((!used[k]) && (!used[m-k])) {
            used[k] = 1;
            used[m-k] = 1;
            used[m] = 1;
            if (solve(m)) {
                printf("%d+%d=%d  ", k, m-k, m);
                return 1;
            }
            used[k] = 0;
            used[m-k] = 0;
            used[m] = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++) {
        printf("\n%d:\n", n);
        if (n % 4 > 1) {
            printf("impossible\n");
            continue;
        }
        int m = 3*n;
        for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
            used[i] = 0;
        }
        solve(m);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a cool proof to show that multiplication is needed for n = 2,3 mod 4! thanks for the clear explanation!