# Find all $n$ such that $1,2,\dots,n$ be divided into disjoint triples such that for each triple, one element is the sum of the other two elements.

Tags: contest-math, additive-combinatorics

Find all $n$ such that $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ be divided into disjoint triples such that for each triple, one element is the sum of the other two elements.

On a 2013 combinatorics handout (high school Math Olympics) of *tian27546西西* (translated into English)

> Assume $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ be divided into disjoint triples, then $3\mid n$. And because each triple can be written in the form of $(a,b,a+b)$, the
> sum of the elements of each triple is even, so $1+2+\dots+n=n(n+1)/2$ is even, so $n$ must be in the form of $12k$, or
> $12k+3$.
>
> Lemma: Assume that there is a division for $n=k$, then there is a division for $n=4k$ or $n=4k+3$.
>
> Proof: $\{2,4,⋯,2k\}$ can be divided in the same way as $\{1,2,⋯,n\}$.
> For $n=4k$, the remaining numbers $\{1,3,⋯,2k-1,2k+1,2k+2,⋯,4k-1,4k\}$ can be divided into $k$ triples $(2j-1,3k-j+1,3k+j),j=1,2,⋯,k$, as follows (each column is a triple):
> \begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 5 & \cdots & 2 k-3 & 2 k-1 \cr
> 3 k & 3 k-1 & 3 k-2 & \cdots & 2 k+2 & 2 k+1 \cr
> 3 k+1 & 3 k+2 & 3 k+3 & \cdots & 4 k-1 & 4 k\end{pmatrix}
> For $n=4k+3$, the remaining numbers $\{1,3,⋯,2k-1,2k+1,⋯,4k+2,4k+3\}$ can be divided into $k+1$ triples $(2i-1,3k+3-j,3k+j+2),j=1,2,⋯,k+1$, we also get the following (each column is a triple) :\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 5 & \cdots & 2 k-1 & 2 k+1 \cr 3 k+2 & 3 k+1 & 3 k & \cdots & 2 k+3 & 2 k+2 \cr 3 k+3 & 3 k+4 & 3 k+5 & \cdots & 4 k+2 & 4 k+3\end{pmatrix}
> Example: Since for $n=3$ there is a division, and$$3 \longrightarrow_{3 \times 4+3} 15 \longrightarrow_{15 \times 4} 60 \longrightarrow_{60 \times 4+3} 243 \longrightarrow_{243 \times 4+3} 975$$so there is a division for $n=975$.

All $n$ that can be reduced to $3$, are $3, 12, 15, 48, 51, 60, 63,\dots$(See [A001196](https://oeis.org/A001196))

There are $n$ that satisfies the condition but can not be reduced to $3$, the smallest ones are $24,27,36,39$. Using the lemma, each of them can produce other numbers.
\begin{array}l
n=24&
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 4 & 7 & 6 & 2 \\
 23 & 19 & 16 & 12 & 14 & 10 & 9 & 11 \\
 24 & 22 & 21 & 20 & 18 & 17 & 15 & 13 \end{pmatrix}\\
n=27&
\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
 11 & 14 & 12 & 10 & 13 & 15 & 20 & 23 & 26 \\
 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 21 & 22 & 24 & 25 & 27 \end{pmatrix}\\
n=36&\begin{pmatrix}
 6 & 8 & 4 & 7 & 12 & 11 & 10 & 9 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
 15 & 14 & 19 & 17 & 13 & 16 & 18 & 20 & 26 & 30 & 32 & 35 \\
 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 31 & 33 & 34 & 36
\end{pmatrix}\\
n=39&\begin{pmatrix}
 7 & 5 & 8 & 6 & 13 & 12 & 11 & 10 & 9 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
 15 & 19 & 17 & 20 & 14 & 16 & 18 & 21 & 23 & 30 & 33 & 35 & 38 \\
 22 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 31 & 32 & 34 & 36 & 37 & 39
\end{pmatrix}
\end{array}
Originally posted by user *realnumber* on [Math Entertainment forum](http://kuing.infinityfreeapp.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3517). I found the above divisions for $24,27,36,39$ by *Mathematica*.

Comment: Similar https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4179825/for-which-n-in-bbb-n-can-we-divide-1-2-3-3n-into-n-subsets-each-wi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A108235](https://oeis.org/A108235) Number of partitions of $\{1,2,...,3n\}$ into $n$ triples $(X,Y,Z)$ each satisfying $X+Y=Z$.
$$\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}=\{1, 0, 0, 8, 21, 0, 0, 3040, 20505, 0, 0, 10567748, 103372655,\\ 0, 0, 142664107305, 1836652173363, 0, 0,\dots\}$$
The desired sequence is$$\{3n:a_n\ne0\}=\{3, 12, 15, 24, 27, 36, 39, 48, 51,\dots\}$$